# pushed openvpn client routes makes the http-proxy server to stop functioning, ip route advice required

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, proxy, iproute

I have both a proxy server and openvpn client running on an openWRT router,
I have to setup a proxy server on the router and then connect the OpenVPN client running on the same router, because the ISP DPI blocks plain OpenVPN traffic toward the **commercial VPN providers**.

Please note that *both* **openvpn client** and the **proxy server** do run on the same router or localhost and as soon as the openvpn client connects to the VPN server via the *http-proxy* defined on the 127.0.0.1 1080 address the **VPN server pushes all it predefined routes** to the router and then the *pushed routes* mess with the default kernel routes on the router and then the proxy server routes also changes and then stops working, and as a result the openvpn client also gets disconnected and then openvpn client gets disconnected later as well.

Once the openvpn client gets disconnected it retries to establish a connection and since the **http-proxy server** has already failed and the route table is messed then the whole router internet gets locked.

*Please note that commercial VPN* providers are not keen to customize their servers for me so I have to omit their  openvpn-server push commands on my client side by using **route-nopull** in the client.ovpn file.

Once the ***route-nopull*** is used in the client.ovpn config file I am totally on my own to setup all the *ip route* and *iptables* commands in the ***route-up script***
file which it path is also defined in the openvpn client config file.
I have tried the ***route-nopull*** directive in the opnevpn client and the client connects to the VPN provider like a charm.

Now I should figure out the contents of the *route-up script* which should **contain a few of the ip routes and iptables commands** I need help with setting them up since all of my efforts to create them has failed.
the *route-up script* runs directly after the tun0 is created and I need assistance for adding the correct commands into it.

My goal is to make the VPN internet traffic available to all devices on the lan interface with dhcp-range *192.168.55.65-192.168.55.127* or *192.168.55.64/26* with subnet mask 255.255.255.255.192

In addition, the router with the ip address 192.168.55.1 and the localhost (127.0.0.1) address should **NOT** get access to the internet via tun0 interface and their source of internet access should **be intact**, if not the prior issue with the http-proxy will show up again,

What I am looking for are the required route and maybe iptables commands that the route-up script should execute once after the tun0 is created for the first time.

As a side note OpenWRT router is based on linux and therefore I mentioned my issue here.
I would be happy if any with good knowledge of linux networking figure out the required **ip route and iptables** commands that solve my problem.

In order to check the validity of the solution following commands should work,

Running command on the Openwrt (router cli)

```
#traceroute www.stackexchange.com
```

By running the above command on the routers CLI it should provide similar nodes/paths as before tun0 creation.

The next command **should run from one of the LAN (br-lan) *connected devices*** with ip-range 192.168.55.65-192.168.55.126 and it should show different nodes since the connected LAN device should get its internet redirected from the tun0 interface and it should shows the tun0 gateway as the next hop,

On any linux OS

```
#traceroute www.stackexchange.com
```

On windows PC

```
C:\>tracert www.stackexchange.com
```

*Note: connected LAN devices are in range 192.168.55.64/26 and they should show tun0 gateway as the next hop.*

FYI on my router CLI I have following setting after tun0 creation with route-nopull but empty route-up script!

```
#netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 phy1-sta0
10.124.148.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 phy1-sta0
192.168.55.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br-lan


#ip route show
default via 192.168.8.1 dev phy1-sta0 proto static src 192.168.8.118
10.124.148.0/23 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.124.148.101
192.168.8.0/24 dev phy1-sta0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.118
192.168.55.0/24 dev br-lan proto kernel scope link src 192.168.55.1
```

Infact the router and the localhost ip should use the phy-sta0 or wan internet gateway of 192.168.8.1 wan which comes from a separate LTE router interface like *prior to the creation of the tun0 and NOT from the tun0*.

Once the tun0 is created the above tables should get changed accordingly only for the connected lan devices (except the router) if and only if the correct *sought after*  **route-up script** is provided.

Thanks